# how to simulate 5 stage of pipe line in c++?

Tags: c++, c, pipeline, instruction-set

I am trying to simulate 5 stage of pipeline. I have saved all the instruction into a struct.
( basically done with the stage of lixcal analysis )

eg:

```
ADD R1 R2 R3 // R1 = R2+ R3 ... struct pipe{ int pc, string instruction , int r1, int r2....}
```

now if `p[i]` is one of the stage of pipeline and ( `p[1]` could be `pc=pc+1`;
       `I[i]` is instructions, ( `I[1]` could be `ADD R1 R2 R3` )

what I want to do is

```
at t=1 : p[1] = I[1]

at t=2 :p[2] = I[1], p[1] = I[2]

at t=3 :p[3] = I[1], p[2] = I[2], p[1] = I[3]

at t=4 :p[4] = I[1], p[3] = I[2], p[2] = I[3], p[1] = I[4]
```

... and goes like that 
I am using c++ so far. how could any one represent this cycle in c++ ?

Comment: In other words, you're trying to create a little ARM-like virtual machine?

Comment: @icktoofay yes exactly

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You described the algorithm in your question, so what do you need?

Comment: kind of how to represent the above loop in c++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just want to add an element at the front of the array at each timestep, thus moving the already existant array elements one to the right. You could avoid doing `O(n**2)` ops like this

```
int& p_at_time(int index, int time_moment) {
    return &p[time_moment-index+1];
}
```

- and at t=1: p_at_time(1,1) = I[1];
- at t=2: p_at_time(1,2) = I[2], (p_at_time(2,2) is already `== I[1]`)
- at t=3: p_at_time(1,3) = I[3], (p_at_time(2,3) and p_at_time(3,3) have the values I[2] 
  and I[1] respectively)